Can't submit GRES value from slurm REST API
I have been trying to submit the slurm GRES flag through the REST API however, I couldn't find a way to do the same through the REST APIs. I am using the parser version 0.0.40
Is this something not yet available? Is there a work around?
This is what I tried.
url: /slurm/0.0.40/job/submit
method: POST
data: {
   "script":"#!/bin/bash \n nvidia-smi",
   "job": {
       "environment": ["PATH=/bin/:/usr/bin/:/sbin/"],
       "gres":"gpu:2",
       "time_limit": 120,
       "name":"test-gpu",
       "standard_output":"output/slurmout-%j.out",
       "current_working_directory":".../slurmapis/5fcceebe-f538-40fa-99c4-66faa71945f7"
    }
}

This is the response I get
{
   "result":{
      "job_id":64426478,
      "step_id":"batch",
      "error_code":0,
      "error":"No error",
      "job_submit_user_msg":""
   },
   "job_id":64426478,
   "step_id":"batch",
   "job_submit_user_msg":"",
   "meta":{
      "plugin":{
         "type":"openapi/slurmctld",
         "name":"Slurm OpenAPI slurmctld",
         "data_parser":"data_parser/v0.0.40",
         "accounting_storage":"accounting_storage/slurmdbd"
      },
      "client":{
         "source":"[host.name]:54014",
         "user":"root",
         "group":"root"
      },
      "command":[
         
      ],
      "slurm":{
         "version":{
            "major":"23",
            "micro":"4",
            "minor":"11"
         },
         "release":"23.11.4",
         "cluster":"clustername"
      }
   },
   "errors":[
      
   ],
   "warnings":[
      {
         "description":"Expected OpenAPI type=object (Slurm type=dictionary) but got OpenAPI type=integer (Slurm type=64 bit integer)",
         "source":"#/job/time_limit/"
      },
      {
         "description":"Ignoring unknown field ""gres"" of type string in DATA_PARSER_JOB_DESC_MSG",
         "source":"#/job/gres/"
      }
   ]
}


After much digging into the API docs, I've successfully used the following parameters to request 1 GPU with 4 CPUs:
SLURM 23.11.6 OpenAPI 0.0.40
url: /slurm/0.0.40/job/submit
method: POST
data: {
   "script":"#!/bin/bash \n nvidia-smi",
   "job": {
       "environment": ["PATH=/bin/:/usr/bin/:/sbin/"],
       "cpus_per_tres": "gres/gpu:4",
       "tres_per_job": "gres/gpu:1",
       "time_limit": 120,
       "name":"test-gpu",
       "standard_output":"output/slurmout-%j.out",
       "current_working_directory":"/fuzz/wah/buzz"
    }
}

Drill down into the REST API docs v0.0.41_job_desc_msg and good luck sorting out the syntax. Something like:
"tres_per_job":"gres/<resource_type>:<num>"
